# Why does max-height not work with tables?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-tables

I want the parent containers of a table to expand as per the height of the table. I tried setting `height:auto;` to the parent containers but it didn't work.

My target is to **keep the table shape in square** and **expand height of the container depending on the height of the table.**
The following is what I tried:

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron playground" style="background-color: #1b6d85;">
    <div class="boardContainer" style="background-color: #2b542c;">
        <table id="boardGrid" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.playground {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.boardContainer {
    height: auto;
}
#boardGrid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 620px;
    max-height: 620px;
}
#boardGrid td {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 33.33%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.comments {
    height: 200px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .boardContainer {
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: 15%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .scoreboard {
        position: fixed;
        right: 10px;
    }
    .playground {
        margin-top: 35px;
    }
    .boardContainer {
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 20%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .boardContainer {
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-right: 25%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would this work for you?
https://jsfiddle.net/wb4ovbsb/2/

```
.playground {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.boardContainer {
    height: 0;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
}
#boardGrid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 620px;
    max-height: 620px;
}
#boardGrid td {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 33.33%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.comments {
    height: 200px;
}
.strecher{position:absolute; top:0; bottom: 0; right:0;left:0;}
table{width:100%; text-align:center; height:100%; vertical-align: middle; }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .boardContainer {
        width: 70%;
        padding-bottom:70%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .scoreboard {
        position: fixed;
        right: 10px;
    }
    .playground {
        margin-top: 35px;
    }
    .boardContainer {
        width: 60%;
        padding-bottom:60%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .boardContainer {
        width: 50%;
        padding-bottom:50%;
    }
}*emphasized text*
```

Comment: the table didnt expand.

Comment: Nope, I want the table to be in square shape all through different viewports and hence the the containing divs to expand on the basis of the table height.

Comment: I don't understand why is it not working for me whereas the fiddle is alright.

Comment: what exactly isn't working, the grid seems square to me

Comment: That link which I gave now has a proper grid as I had to use bit of js to set the height. Although I will check you with a green tick as few lines of your css did help.